Angular Material Theme overwrite my initial style
I am trying to add Angular Material to an existing application that already uses some styles for HTML elements. The problem is that the material theme overwrites the existing CSS for those elements.
This error shows up in my console as well:

Could not find Angular Material core theme. Most Material components may not work as expected. For more info refer to the theming guide: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming`

because I didn't add the theme to my style.scss to keep the original styles. But this stopped my paginator from working as it should.
When I import the theme to my style.scss, my paginator works well, but all the styles are changing.
How can I fix that while also avoiding the theme from overwriting my elements style?
Thanks!

Let's assume that you are using only scss to style html, did you try this method:
app.component.ts


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    // ============== 
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
    //  ===========
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    // ...
})
export class AppComponent { }



app.component.scss
// My elements styles in this file instead of styles.scss !

I hope that fixes it ! or can you provide more code details ?
